# I want to save the output of git command to a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, git

The way I use `var=$(git push origin main)`
I tried `git push origin main > tmp.txt`

and still do the output to the terminal I don't want it to begin output and also I want to store it onto the variable, but the variable is empty

Comment: You're not showing enough code.

Comment: Can't you do `var=$(git push origin main); echo $var` to save the output of the command to the variable and show the output in the terminal?

Comment: When redirecting output to a file, make sure you also redirect stderr: `git push origin main 2>&1 > tmp.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Git prints some of its output to `stderr`, the standard error stream. If you want to capture it in a variable you need to redirect the standard error stream to the standard output stream: `var=$(git push origin main 2>&1)`.